# Sub Projects in one ASP.NET solution not able to share Master page

Tags: asp.net, master-pages, vs-web-application-project

I've been researching this added with banging my head against the wall. I have a WAP solution that will contain several web projects. I want to use one shared site.master page file for all projects.

EXAMPLE
My site.master page will be located in Project1 and in Project2 there is a content page called webform1.aspx I attempted populated the MasterPageFile with several different paths and nothing seems to work. If I click on the pick a masterpagefile context menu to select a Master page only Project two is visible.

```
MasterPageFile="WAP/Site1.Master" 
MasterPageFile="~/WAP/Site1.Master" 
MasterPageFile="../WAP/Site1.Master"
```

No matter what I tried the master page is never found. Is this even possible? I thought I have done this several years back.

Answer (score 0):

Some people have suggested adding the master page to the project as a link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/474836/3435345 but I haven't been able to get that to work.

(I would post this as a comment but don't have enough stackoverflow points.)

Comment: I also tried to "add as a link" and didn't work. Did anyone solve it?

Comment: @Seva, I haven't been able to figure it out with a web forms project. I'm currently converting the project(s) into MVC which allows you to share code/layouts much easier (IMO).